# How to test if my script sh is still running by JAVA

Tags: java, bash, shell, sh

I have a java class that run a number of shell scripts in a loop like follows :

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(file.getAbsolutePath() + "/script.sh");
}
```

In that same class, after 3 minutes I want to test if a script sh is still running, if yes then move to the execution of second script.sh, if no then wait until it's done.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After recording the Process instance:

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

you can call this to wait for it to end after whatever time period you wish later:

```
 p.waitFor();
```

or

```
 p.waitFor(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the returned `Process` instance from the `exec` method in a variable, and call `Process#isAlive` to see if it is still running.

Example:

```java
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("script.sh");
Thread.currentThread().wait(100);
if(p.isAlive()){
     // Do something
}
```

Comment: the problem is that p.isAlive is always returning false even though my process is still running.. have you any idea why?

Comment: How did you know it was still running? Are you sure it is the instance created by your java program, not by something else?

Comment: I knew why it was still running, actually to run it on windows, i've changed the code to Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start "+ "/script.sh"); So when I do p.isAlive it tests if cmd.exe is alive not .sh, have you any suggestions to test the subprocess?

Comment: the command cmd start starts a new process and the old process does not represent the script i believe.

Comment: I don't quiet understand.. you mean the start started the new process which is .sh process, the old one is cmd.exe so the process p referes to cmd.exe? If that's what you mean how could I test the .sh process if still Alive.